# Laravel Relationship's

Tags: php, laravel

I have a little difficulty in Laravel Relationships. I made all the relationships between CourseModel, CourseTimeModel and CourseInstructorModel. But the problem is that i want to get instructor_name from instructor table. Is it possible that i can get the instructor_name from instructor table using relationship?

**CourseModel.php**

```
class CourseModel extends Model {

    protected $table = 'course';

    protected $fillable = [
       'course_name',
       'fee',
       'duration',
       'description',
       'created_at',
       'updated_at',
    ];

    public function courseInstructor() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CourseInstructorModel');
    }

    public function courseTime() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CourseTimeModel');
    }

    public function getCourses() {
        $courses = $this->with(['courseTime', 'courseInstructor'])->paginate(10);
        return $courses;
    }
}
```

**CourseInstructorModel.php**

```
class CourseInstructorModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'course_instructor';

    protected $fillable = [
        'course_id',
        'instructor_id', 
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CourseModel');    
    } 
}
```

**CourseTimeModel.php**

```
class CourseTimeModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'course_time';

    protected $fillable = [
        'course_time',
        'course_id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CourseModel');    
    } 
}
```

Comment: Where is the error? Where do you try to use your relations?

Comment: I am trying to get all the courses through CourseModel@getCourses() using relation's.

Comment: $course = CourseModel::find(n); $course_instructors = $course->courseInstructor; $course_times = $course->courseTime()->paginate(10);

Comment: I see that you try to do that, but what exactly is not working? Where is the problem? For me the getCoursers function shouldnt be in the model. This is controller code, there you simply call $courses = App\Course::with(['courseTime', 'courseInstructor'])->paginate(10); - you could also define a scope for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using Many to Many Relationship between CourseModel and InstructorModel.
Here is my code that i write in **CourseModel.php**

```
public function instructor() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Instructor');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get instructor_name in this way :

```
$courseModel = CourseModel::find(1);
$instructor_name = $courseModel->courseInstructor->instructor_name;
```